# Is it alright to use multiple classes?

Tags: css

Instead of giving a background-color, border, etc. to each element, I decided to make a list of classes like red-background, blue-text, border-1px and others ...
Is it fine to do this or not. If not how I should then?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyeYZ.png)

Thanks for answers, I was just unsure about if I'm doing well or not. I will try to give a better naming.

Comment: Why shouldn't that be fine? If it works for you, go on with that

Comment: Not only is it fine, it's the defacto standard in CSS frameworks like Bootstrap. `class="mx-5 my-2"` for instance, for defining top-bottom margins (`my`) and l/r margins (`mx`). Is there something specific you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm just not sure if I'm doing well in organizing CSS, I'm kinda new in this and still have a lot to learn. I just use multiple classes when there are multiple elements that have something in common.

Answer (score 2):

That type of approach is called `utility-classes` and has been greatly spread by [Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/) framework. Which makes use of small descriptive classes instead of already made and opinionated component classes like the ones from Bootstrap.

This approach has the **multiple pros**, like simplicity, composability, and reusability.

But they will also probably make your **classes be really long** for each of your html tags.

There is nothing wrong with this, it's a matter of what works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

Some css libraries or frameworks use approaches like that.
For instance in bootstrap you can use `hidden` to hide an element via the `display: none;` prop.

This is refered in some places as utility/helper classes.

Answer (score 0):

That's a good idea and a good approach to have several classes. But from the naming perspective, that's better to use names that will describe the behavior, instead of color or border with. Declarative vs imperative. For example instead of blue-text is better to use common-text, because your blue can easily become green/black gray later.